# Fancybox 3 open using api method and share button

Tags: share, fancybox-3

I want to open fancybox with open api method and have share menu.

```
<a class="box" href="https://source.unsplash.com/juHayWuaaoQ/1500x1000" data- 
 fancybox="images" data-caption="Backpackers following a dirt trail">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/juHayWuaaoQ/240x160" />
</a>
```

This opens the image when clicked but the share button is missing. How can I have share button?

https://jsfiddle.net/92vepwLr/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `buttons` option to specify buttons in the toolbar. Example:

HTML

```
<a class="item">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/juHayWuaaoQ/240x160" />
</a>
```

JS

```
$('.item').on('click', function() {
  $.fancybox.open({
    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/juHayWuaaoQ/1500x1000",
    opts: {
      thumb: "https://source.unsplash.com/juHayWuaaoQ/240x160",
      caption: "lorem ipsum dolor",
            buttons: ['zoom', 'share', 'close']
    }
  });
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/8mh15gwd/